# Trying to use an else if statement?

Tags: java

My code is a guessing game: the user gets to choose either 5,10, or 20 tries, and has that many times to guess a randomNumber choses by the computer. My code takes each guess and prints out if their guess is higher or lower than the randomNumber if their guess is wrong, and prints out a congratulations message if their guess is right. 
I need to have a message that says: "Sorry, (the users name), you did not guess the magic number, (randomNumber), in (how ever many guesses they chose) tries."
This is only after they've used all their guesses and still haven't guessed the number.
I wrote my code by I am getting an error that says I have an else without an If, but I feel like that might not be my only problem. Can someone tell me how to include this in my code?
Here it is:

Comment: Try adding braces to your if statement. The lack of braces may have lead Java to think there's no corresponding else statement, especially since your if-block is multi-line.

Comment: If you are not confident enough, don't write code in a plain textpad. try an IDE. It will show you the syntax check error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be help you.

```
 for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfGuesses; i++){
   System.out.print("Enter guess #"+i+": ");
   guess = scan.nextInt();
        if (guess > randomNumber)
                    System.out.println("Your guess, "+guess+", is greater than the magic number.");
        else if (guess < randomNumber)
                    System.out.println("Your guess, "+guess+" is less than the magic number.");
        else if (guess == randomNumber){
                    System.out.println("Congratulations, "+name+"! You guessed the magic number in "+i+" guesses.");
                    break;
                }
        if (i == numberOfGuesses)
             System.out.println("Sorry, "+ name+"you did not guess the magic number,"+ randomNumber+"in"+numberOfGuesses+ "tries.");

    }
```

Output:

```
Please enter your name: user
Would you like to try to guess a number? (Yes or No):yes
How many guesses would you like? (5, 10, 20)5
Enter guess #1: 1
Your guess, 1 is less than the magic number.
Enter guess #2: 100
Your guess, 100, is greater than the magic number.
Enter guess #3: 2
Your guess, 2 is less than the magic number.
Enter guess #4: 3
Your guess, 3 is less than the magic number.
Enter guess #5: 4
Your guess, 4 is less than the magic number.
Sorry, useryou did not guess the magic number,71in5tries.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error lies here:

```
break;
```

When using **break**, the **if** statement gets cancelled. That's why you get that error.

Think about it for a second:

You put an **if** statement with several **else if's** afterwards.

When you say **break**, your program assumes that you're done with all of the statements and expects something new to start.

In your code, that "something new" is an **else** - which obviously doesn't work, as there is no **if** statement that it can logically access.

Long story short - when using **if** and **else if**, you don't really need to use **break**. Curly brackets are - in most cases - more than sufficient.

I hope that helped you. If you still have any questions left, hit me up.